# Django: troubles because of not having admin.py

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

OK, I`m writing an app using this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/

The whole article says that I must work with admin.py which does not exist in my directory (it wasn`t created). For example, here is the class

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Choice
extra = 3
```

I work in models.py. I`ve change the word 'admin' to a word 'models'.

Imports I have:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
```

Manage.py syncdb says:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StackedInline'
```

So what should I do?

Thanks a lot.

P.S. Actually, I couldn`t just create admin.py in my directory, could I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn`t just create admin.py in my directory, could I?

Yes, you could... and you should `:)`

The [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin) says:

> ...create a file called admin.py in your polls directory...

Answer (score 0):

> I`ve change the word 'admin' to a word 'models'.

You should not do that.